# PostgreSQL point_ops with GiST PostGIS Spatial Index

Tags: performance, postgresql, indexing, postgis

The [9.0 release notes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/release-9-0.html) for PostgreSQL states the following change:

> Add point_ops operator class for GiST (Teodor Sigaev)
>
> This feature permits GiST indexing of point columns. The index can be
>   used for several types of queries such as `point <@ polygon` (point is
>   in polygon). This should make many PostGIS queries faster.

I have a very large table (millions of rows) with a `GEOMETRY(POINT,[SRID])` column that I sometimes compare to polygons. Do I need to do anything to enable this when creating the index? Do I have to use the operator they indicate, or would this work with [`ST_Contains`](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Contains.html)?

(I'm sure the answer is in the docs somewhere, but I can't find it.)

Answer (score 5):

It's an opclass, so you specify it in the `CREATE INDEX` command:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_name ON tablename USING GiST (col_name point_ops);
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped. I went and read the PostgreSQL documentation on operator classes, but I'm still a bit lost as to how this works with PostGIS. What operators can use indexes created with `point_ops`? Can `ST_Contains` (which uses `&&` internally), or do I need to use the `<@` operator? Googling about it, this question is the first thing that comes up, so it doesn't look like there's much info out there to be found.

Comment: @jpmc26 I haven't worked enough with PostGIS... I'd recommend posting on the PostGIS mailing list or pgsql-general. Link to this question if you do.